# Reading from AddressBook database in Today Extension (OS X)

Tags: macos, abaddressbook, osx-yosemite

It seems to be that Today Extensions (Widgets) are unable to access contact records via the `ABAddressBook.framework`. Apple is saying:

> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is
>   ineligible to participate in certain activities. An app extension
>   cannot:
>
> Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the
>   methods on that object Use any API marked in header files with the
>   **NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE** macro, or similar unavailability macro, or
>   any API in an unavailable framework For example, in iOS 8.0, the
>   HealthKit framework and EventKit UI framework are unavailable to app
>   extensions.

However, I cannot find any of these *NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE* markers in the headers of ABAddressBook.framework.

So I'm wondering if it's either my or Apple fault here?

PS: Yes, AddressBook access is set to YES in the entitlements.